# Slack: show taskbar badge unread-messages icon only for single workspace

Tags: windows-7, notifications, notification-area, slack

In slack desktop, when you're signed in to several workspaces, how do you make the taskbar unread-messages notification icon (the blue circle) appear only for one given workspace?

[image]

Comment: I would love this too. Following some channels with lots of notifications. But I really just want to know if my main - but quieter - workspace has any notifications